# Installing Passenger-Apache2 on OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, osx-snow-leopard

I'm trying to get passenger up and running to serve my rails app. I'm running rails 1.9.1 on a Mac running OS X 10.6.8. I've been able to install the passenger gem but when I run the command:

```
sudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```

The installation fails after a couple of minutes and says

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___fork", referenced from:
      Passenger::asyncFork()     in Utils.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [g++ buildout/agents/PassengerHelperAgent.o -o buildout/agents/PassengerHelperAgent buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Logging.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/SystemTime.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/StrIntUtils.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/IOUtils.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/Base64.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/CachedFileStat.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/LargeFiles.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/ApplicationPool2/Implementation.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/ApplicationPool2/AppTypes.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/AgentsBase.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/MD5.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/fib.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/jsoncpp.o buildout/common/libboost_oxt.a  buildout/libev/.libs/libev.a buildout/libeio/.libs/libeio.a -lpthread -Wl,-dead_strip ]

Tasks: TOP => apache2 => buildout/agents/PassengerHelperAgent
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to rails so I apologize if this is a stupid error on my part. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did get it to work (So Phusion Passenger not working on Snow Leopard is not the correct answer). I ended up installing passenger through homebrew with the command:

```
brew install passenger
```

and then installed it again using

```
sudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```

So if anybody else runs across this you might give that a try.

Comment: I got the same error as you, but your solution didn't work for me on OSX 10.6.8. This is what I got: `$ brew install passenger`.  Output: `passenger: OS X Lion or newer is required. Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.`

Comment: Based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25241935/1714), I installed v4.0.5 (`sudo gem install passenger -v 4.0.5`), and `sudo passenger-install-apache2-module` worked.  I didn't bother testing versions between 4.0.5 and 4.0.48 (which fails with the error above)

Answer (score 0):

This is because of an incompatibility of Phusion Passenger with Snow Leopard. Phusion Passenger no longer supports Snow Leopard.