# Passenger install with conversion errors. Impact on nginx module?

Tags: passenger, osx-snow-leopard

Under OS X 10.6.8 installing passenger, first under rbenv, then after uninstalling rbenv, also under rvm

```
Mini:~ user$ gem install passenger
```

is generating conversion errors:

```
unable to convert "\xE4" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for CHANGELOG, skipping
unable to convert "\xC5" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for CONTRIBUTORS, skipping
unable to convert "\xC3" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for debian.template/copyright, skipping
unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for doc/Security of user switching support.idmap.txt, skipping
unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for doc/Users guide Apache.idmap.txt, skipping
unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for doc/Users guide Nginx.idmap.txt, skipping
unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for doc/Users guide Standalone.idmap.txt, skipping
unable to convert "\xC3" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for ext/common/Utils/Base64.cpp, skipping
unable to convert "\xC3" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for ext/common/Utils/Base64.h, skipping
unable to convert "\xC2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for ext/libeio/Changes, skipping
unable to convert "\xC2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for ext/libeio/ecb.h, skipping
unable to convert "\xC3" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for ext/libev/Changes, skipping
unable to convert "\xC2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for ext/libev/ev.c, skipping
unable to convert U+2713 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/phusion_passenger/config/validate_install_command.rb, skipping
unable to convert U+00A9 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/phusion_passenger/utils/json.rb, skipping
unable to convert U+2023 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/phusion_passenger/utils/terminal_choice_menu.rb, skipping
unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for test/cxx/UtilsTest.cpp, skipping
Installing ri documentation for passenger-4.0.48
unable to convert "\xC3" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for README.rdoc, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for test/multipart/binary, skipping
unable to convert U+00F8 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for test/spec_utils.rb, skipping
```

I went ahead and installed the nginx module

```
Mini:~ user$ passenger-install-nginx-module
```

with unhappy results in red...

```
It looks like something went wrong
```

I surmise that the conversion errors are at the root of some issues. particularly worrisome is the fat that some hit files in config directories...

Assuming an uninstall, how can these be installed without conversion errors?

`ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/passenger-4.0.48/`
is the environment

**Update**
The errors apparently are only relative to the documentation.

```
 gem install passenger --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

does install passenger 4.0.48.

nginx however fails to install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd better to just update the `rdoc` gem:

`gem install rdoc`

The bug comes about due to `rdoc` trying to read a binary file. This bug was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The errors apparently are only relative to the documentation.

```
 gem install passenger --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

does install passenger 4.0.48.

However, nginx would not install because of OS X version.

on Snow Leopard the latest version one can install, then have nginx installed is:

```
gem install passenger -v 4.0.5
```